# Finding if a minimum cut in a flow network where we force certain nodes to be in certain sides of the cut

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

We are given a flow network and two nodes `u` and `v`. We want to create an algorithm that tells us whether or not there is a minimum s-t cut so that `u` belongs to the same side of the cut as the source node `s` and `v` belongs to the same side of the cut as the sink node `t`.

I know how to find a min cut after running Ford-Fulkerson, but since min cuts are not necessarily unique, I'm not sure how to test if there is a min cut with `u` and `s` on one side and `t` and `v` on another.

Comment: Hint: what happens if we add an arc with very large capacity from s to u before running F--F?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Is arc the same thing as an edge? If so then I think adding an edge (s,u) with large capacity would mean that if all outgoing edges from u were not fully saturated, then with this extra edge they would be fully saturated? But wouldn't this change the max flow value potentially?

Comment: Yes, an arc is a directed edge. If it does change the max flow value, what can you conclude?

Comment: If the max flow increases then so does the value of the min cut for that network flow system. But I'm a bit confused as to why that implies that there is no min cut with s,u on one side and t,v on another side in the original graph (without (s,u) edge)

Comment: If there were such a min cut, how would its capacity change?

Comment: Ah so is the logic something like this: if there is an s-t cut with `s` ,`u` on one side then all outgoing edges from `u` are fully saturated. If after adding (s,u) with large capacity the flow goes up then that means that `u` was not originally saturated in the original network flow setup which means there is no s-t cut with `s` ,`u` on the same side. How  do i introduce the v,t being in same cut condition to this argument?

Comment: It's symmetric.